# How to direct compute engine startup script to execute within docker container

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to run a startup script on gcp compute engine. The script boots, starts a docker container, and runs commands from within that container. Outside of startup script, the whole thing works without error, but clearly startup scripts are not designed for this task?

I call.

```
gcloud compute instances create cloudml
    --image-family=container-vm
    --image-project=google-containers
    --boot-disk-size "40"
    --service-account "773889352370-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
    --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" 
    --metadata-from-file startup-script=Training.sh
```

I can monitor the logs of the startup script through the serial port. I can see it correctly grab the script and start.

The first command is docker run

```
sudo docker run -it --privileged -- gcr.io/api-project-773889352370/cloudmlengine
```

From the logs, there it goes pulling and extracting

```
Jul 24 21:54:02 cloudml startupscript: latest: Pulling from api-project-773889352370/cloudmlengine
Jul 24 21:54:02 cloudml startupscript: 9f0706ba7422: Pulling fs layer
Jul 24 21:54:02 cloudml startupscript: ec542cd45f0c: Pulling fs layer
Jul 24 21:54:02 cloudml startupscript: 07bcbd00d9b4: Pulling fs layer
Jul 24 21:54:02 cloudml startupscript: acc6d9961302: Pulling fs layer
Jul 24 21:54:02 cloudml startupscript: ef130a4b8961: Pulling fs layer
Jul 24 21:54:02 cloudml startupscript: 5ecac320219d: Pulling fs layer
Jul 24 21:54:02 cloudml startupscript: 54110f0dc661: Pulling fs layer
```

and eventually

```
downloaded newer image for gcr.io/api-project-773889352370/cloudmlengine:latest
```

Great. That command should start a container. I'd like the rest of the script to be run from within the container. From ssh this is no problem, docker run -it brings me an interactive prompt, but clearly startup scripts do not work similarly. The next command is

```
git clone https://github.com/bw4sz/DeepMeerkat.git
```

but whole thing kinda peters out without a clear error

```
Jul 24 21:59:53 [  422.646195] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth8286626: link is not ready
cloudml kernel: [  422.639552] device veth8286626 entered promiscuous mode
Jul 24 21:59:53 cloudml kernel: [  422.646195] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth8286626: link is not ready
[  422.938314] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth8286626: link becomes ready
[  422.945723] docker0: port 1(veth8286626) entered forwarding state
[  422.951977] docker0: port 1(veth8286626) entered forwarding state
[  422.962994] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): docker0: link becomes ready
Jul 24 21:59:53 cloudml kernel: [  422.938314] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth8286626: link becomes ready
Jul 24 21:59:53 cloudml kernel: [  422.945723] docker0: port 1(veth8286626) entered forwarding state
Jul 24 21:59:53 cloudml kernel: [  422.951977] docker0: port 1(veth8286626) entered forwarding state
Jul 24 21:59:53 cloudml kernel: [  422.962994] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): docker0: link becomes ready
[  437.956027] docker0: port 1(veth8286626) entered forwarding state
Jul 24 22:00:08 cloudml kernel: [  437.956027] docker0: port 1(veth8286626) entered forwarding state
Jul 24 22:00:29 cloudml sshd[3043]: Did not receive identification string from 139.162.75.112
Jul 24 22:02:26 cloudml sshd[3079]: Invalid user ftpuser from 128.199.72.218
Jul 24 22:02:26 cloudml sshd[3079]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ftpuser [preauth]
Jul 24 22:02:26 cloudml sshd[3079]: Connection closed by 128.199.72.218 [preauth]
Jul 24 22:06:07 cloudml sshd[3168]: Invalid user ftpuser1 from 128.199.72.218
Jul 24 22:06:07 cloudml sshd[3168]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ftpuser1 [preauth]
Jul 24 22:06:07 cloudml sshd[3168]: Connection closed by 128.199.72.218 [preauth]
```

and it goes on like that for awhile.

I can later ssh and try the docker command and the next command (git clone) and they run without a problem, so the docker pull was successful, no errors there.

```
Ben@cloudml:~$ sudo docker run -it --privileged -- gcr.io/api-project-773889352370/cloudmlengine
root@7d8ae18c2295:/#
root@7d8ae18c2295:/# git clone https://github.com/bw4sz/DeepMeerkat.git
Cloning into 'DeepMeerkat'...
remote: Counting objects: 768, done.
remote: Total 768 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 768
Receiving objects: 100% (768/768), 41.38 MiB | 44.71 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (517/517), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
root@7d8ae18c2295:/#
```

Am I going about this wrong way? Perhaps info [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/837518/running-container-vm-on-google-cloud-compute) This is just a one off job, creating a whole kubernetes cluster seems wrong.